# Powershell: Read Text file line by line and split on "|"

Tags: powershell, csv, text-parsing

I am having trouble splitting a line into an array using the "|" in a text file and reassembling it in a certain order. There are multiple lines like the original line in the text file.

This is the original line:

```
80055555|Lastname|Firstname|AidYear|DCDOCS|D:\BDMS_UPLOAD\800123456_11-13-2018 14-35-53 PM_1.pdf
```

I need it to look this way:

```
80055555|DCDOCS|Lastname|Firstname|AidYear|D:\BDMS_UPLOAD\800123456_11-13-2018 14-35-53 PM_1.pdf
```

Here is the code I am working with:

```
$File = 'c:\Names\Complete\complete.txt'
$Arr = $File -split '|'
foreach ($line in Get-Content $File)
{
  $outputline = $Arr[0] + "|" + $Arr[4] + "|" + $Arr[1] + "|" + $Arr[2] + "|" + 
    "@@" + $Arr[5] |
      Out-File -filepath "C:\Names\Complete\index.txt" -Encoding "ascii" -append 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to process every line of the file on its own and then split them.

```
$File = get-content "D:\test\1234.txt"
foreach ($line in $File){
    $Arr = $line.Split('|')
    [array]$OutputFile +=  $Arr[0] + "|" + $Arr[4] + "|" + $Arr[1] + "|" + $Arr[2] + "|" + "@@" + $Arr[5] 
}
$OutputFile | out-file -filepath "D:\test\4321.txt" -Encoding "ascii" -append
```

---

edit: Thx to LotPings for this alternate suggestion based on `-join` and the avoidance of `+=` to build the array (which is inefficient, because it rebuilds the array on every iteration):

```
$File = get-content "D:\test\1234.txt"
$OutputFile = foreach($line in $File){($line.split('|'))[0,4,1,2,3,5] -Join '|'}
$OutputFile | out-file -filepath "D:\test\4321.txt" -Encoding "ascii"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your input file is actually a CSV file without headers and where the fields are separated by the pipe symbol `|`, why not use `Import-Csv` like this:

```
$fileIn  = 'C:\Names\Complete\complete.txt'
$fileOut = 'C:\Names\Complete\index.txt'
(Import-Csv -Path $File -Delimiter '|' -Header 'Item','LastName','FirstName','AidYear','Type','FileName' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        "{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}|{5}" -f $_.Item, $_.Type, $_.LastName, $_.FirstName, $_.AidYear, $_.FileName
    }
) | Add-Content -Path $fileOut -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: Super! It worked perfectly! I will add this to my toolkit for future use as well!

Answer (score 2):

To offer a more PowerShell-idiomatic solution:

```
# Sample input line.
$line = '80055555|Lastname|Firstname|AidYear|DCDOCS|D:\BDMS_UPLOAD\800123456_11-13-2018 14-35-53 PM_1.pdf'

# Split by '|', rearrange, then re-join with '|'
($line -split '\|')[0,4,1,2,3,5] -join '|'
```

Note how PowerShell's indexing syntax (inside `[...]`) is flexible enough to accept an arbitrary *array* (list) of indices to extract.

Also note how [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)'s RHS operand is `\|`, i.e., an *escaped* `|` char., given that `|` has special meaning there, because it is interpreted as a [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions).

To put it all together:

```
$File = 'c:\Names\Complete\complete.txt'
Get-Content $File | ForEach-Object {
  ($_ -split '\|')[0,4,1,2,3,5] -join '|'
} | Out-File -LiteralPath C:\Names\Complete\index.txt -Encoding ascii
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$Arr = $File -split '|'`

Primarily, the problem is that the `-split` operation is applied to the input *file path*, not to the file's *content*.

Secondarily, as noted above, to split by a *literal* `|` char., `\|` must be passed to `-split`, because it expects a *regex* (regular expression).

Also, instead of using `Out-File` *inside a loop* with `-Append`, it is more efficient to use a *single pipeline* with `ForEach-Object`, as shown above.